# CameraX: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-camerax

Attempting to add the following dependencies to my app:

```
// CameraX core library
def camerax_version = "1.0.0-beta01"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:$camerax_version"

// CameraX Camera2 extensions
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$camerax_version"

// CameraX Lifecycle library
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:$camerax_version"

// CameraX View class
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha08"
```

I receive the following error:

```
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource compilation failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/adam/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/ebbf69df6983e5bff0cfe1365273c65d/camera-view-1.0.0-alpha08/res/values/values.xml","position":{"startLine":2,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":55,"endLine":24,"endColumn":24,"endOffset":901}}],"original":"/Users/adam/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/ebbf69df6983e5bff0cfe1365273c65d/camera-view-1.0.0-alpha08/res/values/values.xml:3:5-25:25: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/scaleType' with config ''.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource compilation failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/adam/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/ebbf69df6983e5bff0cfe1365273c65d/camera-view-1.0.0-alpha08/res/values/values.xml","position":{"startLine":2,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":55,"endLine":24,"endColumn":24,"endOffset":901}}],"original":"/Users/adam/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/ebbf69df6983e5bff0cfe1365273c65d/camera-view-1.0.0-alpha08/res/values/values.xml:3:5-25:25: AAPT: error: resource previously defined here.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource compilation failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/adam/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml"}],"original":"/Users/adam/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}

> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource compilation failed
     /Users/adam/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/ebbf69df6983e5bff0cfe1365273c65d/camera-view-1.0.0-alpha08/res/values/values.xml:3:5-25:25: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/scaleType' with config ''.

     /Users/adam/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/ebbf69df6983e5bff0cfe1365273c65d/camera-view-1.0.0-alpha08/res/values/values.xml:3:5-25:25: AAPT: error: resource previously defined here.

     /Users/adam/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.
```

Screenshot of error and files in question:

[image: Screenshot of error and files in question]

I can successfully compile by removing the following dependency:

```
// CameraX View class
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha08"
```

However, I do need it based on [this post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/androids-camerax-jetpack-library-is-now-in-beta-bf4cf0cc3ea6). I'm doing exactly what they're doing [here](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/master/CameraXBasic/app/build.gradle) and their app seems to build just fine

Comment: Seems like another view/custom view in your app has the `scaleType` attribute defined. There could only be one attribute with a given name once an app's resources are merged. CameraX's view artifact includes the custom view `CameraView`, which defines the `scaleType` attribute.

Comment: @HusaynHakeem The weird thing is that it doesn't show the error for the other scaleType though, just this one.

Comment: I'm wondering if this could be due to a conflict with a cached `values.xml` file. Did you try to invalidate the cache then rebuilding the project?

Comment: @HusaynHakeem Yup tried cleaning build, invalidating and restarting, invalidating, closing project completely, and then removing from the AS startup project picker menu. Anything else I might have missed?

Comment: Not that I can think of at the moment. If you have the project on github, I can check it out and see if I run into the same issue.

Comment: @HusaynHakeem Darn, I can't unfortunately because it's a company project :/ I might need to wait for a fix from Google?

Comment: This doesn't require a fix from google. `androidx.camera:camera-view`  defines a `scaleType` attribute which seems to be conflicting with another `scaleType` attribute definition in your project. If you haven't added it, it might be defined in one of the dependencies in your project.

Comment: Turns out it was Twilio! Their 5.4.0 update rolled out a fix for this by prefixing the scaleType attribute

Comment: There you go! :)